# Correct way to return stl map by reference / Is this behavior well defined?

Tags: c++, stl, reference

I have 2 classes and one of them has `map<string, vector<string> >`I want to be able to use this in other class. Here is my code:

```
class a
{
    map<string, vector<string> > m;
    public:
    const map<string, vector<string> > & get()
    {
        return m;
    }
};

class b
{
    a obj;
    public:
    void test()
    {
        map<string, vector<string> > m= obj.get();
        // and then print
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    b bobj;
    bobj.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Is the way I returned reference to map in `class a` correct? It worked,but I just want to confirm if it was done properly / I got lucky / any other comments about the code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i would typedef the map to reduce repetition

Comment: What do you have `b` for? This is C++, you can have free functions!

Comment: @Rookie, Good idea thanks!Rest everything is ok?

Comment: @sbi, You are right, but it just a part of the program I am working on.Rest everything ok?

Comment: Detail: You should change the function signature to `const map<string, vector<string> > & get() const` to make it const-friendly.

Comment: I think that this is bad encapsulation. Also this has the possibility of breaking the const-correctness of your program, see Item 29 in Effective C++.

Comment: @tenfour , Right! totally forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: @Asgeir, bad encapsulation because I am exposing the internal data (map) to some other class?

Comment: @Asgeir: According to http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=020163371X&rll=1, item 29 is about reference counting. Or are you talking about a different edition of the book? (Ed 1&2 differ from ed 3.)

Comment: Yes bad encapsulation because you are exposing an inner detail of the implementation of the class.
@sbi Sorry you're right, second edition. "Item 29:  Avoid returning "handles" to internal data."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you do not want to change the map in `b::test()`, you should not make a copy of it:

```
const map<string, vector<string> >& m = obj.get(); // note the const &
```

My objections:

1. Major: `a::get()` should be `const`:

   ```
   const map<string, vector<string> > & get() const // note the const at the end
   ```
2. Minor: I would create an alias for the map's type using `typedef`.

   ```
   typedef map<string, vector<string> > my_map_t;
   ```
3. Minor: I can't see at all what `b` is for.

Given these, my code would look like this:

```
class a
{
    public:
      typedef map<string, vector<string> > my_map_t;

      const my_map_t & get() const {return m;}

    private:
      my_map_t m;
};

void test(const a& obj)
{
    const a::my_map_t& m = obj.get();
    // and then print
}

int main()
{
    a obj;
    test(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I got it now. Shouldn't it be  - const my_map_t & m = obj.get() (in test function?)

Comment: @iammilind: Thanks for fixing. I really should have tried to compiled this. `:(` Sorry, @Ian.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the correct way to return a reference to a constant object.

However, in your `test` function where you receive the returned reference, the left hand side is not a reference.  That means you're actually going to create a copy of the entire map in this function.  A simple change will fix that problem, and then the `test` function becomes zero copy:

```
void test()
{
    map< string, vector<string> > const & m = obj.get();
    // and then print
}
```

Comment: Correct, and if I might add: If you really want to make a copy, return by value is probably quicker.

Comment: @daramarak: in what way would it be faster? All that would do is *force* the caller to make a copy. If he wants a copy, returning by const reference is still best. But as everyone is hinting, I doubt he really wants to make a copy.

Comment: @tenour: daramarak might be right, though: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @sbi: in the best case, it will be the same speed, not faster.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, but you should use a reference to store the result of `obj.get()`, as mentioned previously. It would have been incorrect if you would have done something like this:

```
const map< string, vector<string> >& foo()
{
    map< string, vector<string> > m;
    // ...
    return m;
}
```

because, in this case, `m` will not exist anymore after `foo()` completes execution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly answering your question, let me show you a very simple example. Consider a simple class A having a double as its private member.

```
class A{

private:

  double a;

public:

  A(double _a);

  double
  get_a();

  double&
  get_aref();

  const double&
  get_aconstref();

};
```

The implementation of that class. Very simple

```
A::A(double _a): a(_a){

};

// Getters
double
A::get_a() {
  return a;
}

double&
A::get_aref(){
  return a;
}

const double&
A::get_aconstref(){
  return a;
}
```

Now lets get to the main program that uses class A.

```
int main(){

  A ainst(6.0);

  double a = ainst.get_a();
  std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
  a++;
  std::cout << "a+1 = " << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Meanwhile, in class A, value of a = " << ainst.get_a() << std::endl;

  double& aref = ainst.get_aref();
  std::cout << "aref = " << aref << std::endl;
  aref++;
  std::cout << "aref+1 = " << aref << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Meanwhile, in class A, value of a = " << ainst.get_a() << std::endl;

  const double& aconstref = ainst.get_aconstref();
  std::cout << "aconstref = " << aconstref << std::endl;

//  aconstref++;
//  std::cout << "aconstref+1 = " << aconstref << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Meanwhile, in class A, value of a = " << ainst.get_a() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

So you can only do a
`const double& aconstref = ainst.get_aconstref();`
and not
`double& aconstref = ainst.get_aconstref();`
if a method of a class returns one of the class members of type T in the form const T&, it means that it does not want the caller to change that member. In the above example, T is a double. Substitute a std::map in nits place and the same logic holds. I hope that is pretty explanatory. If you remove the two commented lines, the compiler complains since you are trying to change that reference.